# Defining one-to-one relationship in EF core with composite keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have a problem regarding a relationship in an existing database. EF creates automatically a shadow property `PayloadVersionId1` but I don't know why. I need to create a one-on-one relationship between a log and a payload, where the payload is the dependent entity (using .net 6 with EF Core). I can not change any database fields or PK constraints. What do I need to change in my configuration in order to correctly define the relationship?

EF migrationmessage:

*The foreign key property 'Log.PayloadVersionId1' was created in shadow state because a conflicting property with the simple name 'PayloadVersionId' exists in the entity type, but is either not mapped, is already used for another relationship, or is incompatible with the associated primary key type.*

Models:

Log

```
    public class Log
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }
        public int PayloadVersionId { get; set; }
        
        // other code...
    }
```

Payload

```
    public class Payload
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public int PayloadVersionId { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreationDateTime { get; set; }
        public string MessageType { get; set; } = null!;

        // other code...

        public virtual MessageLog Log { get; set; } = null!;
    }
```

Log Configuration:

```
            builder.HasKey(e => new { e.Id, e.CreationDateTime })
                .HasName("PKMessageLogID");

            // This needs change!
            builder.HasOne(e => e.Payload)
                .WithOne(e => e.Log)
                .HasForeignKey<MessagePayload>(e => new { e.Id, e.CreationDateTime })
                .IsRequired();

            // other code...
```

Payload Configuration:

```
            builder.HasKey(e => new { e.Id, e.PayloadVersionId, e.MessageType });

            // other code...
```

Comment: have you reversed the relation and using this: ``PayloadBuilder.HasOne(e => e.Log) .WithOne(e => e.Payload) .HasForeignKey(e => new { e.Id, e.CreationDateTime }) .IsRequired();`` Or you need to specify the ``PayloadVersionId`` in the foreignKey too